Google App Script - capture multiple ranges selected by user
My script is to run on a trigger (on edit) and I am trying to capture multiple, non-adjacent ranges selected by the spreadsheet user. From help on this site, I know that the following
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rangeList = sheet.getRangeList(['D4', 'B2:C4']);
rangeList.activate();

will "set" the ranges that can then be processed using
getSelection().getActiveRangeList().getRanges()
I view this as the equivalent of a spreadsheet user highlighting B2:D4 and then ctrl+left click D4.    Is this a correct assumption?
How then can I retrieve the range list as set by the user?
From a previous response in this site
var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
var rangeList = activeSheet.getRangeList(['A1:B4', 'D1:E4']);
rangeList.activate();

var selection = activeSheet.getSelection();

// Active Ranges: A1:B4, D1:E4
var ranges =  selection.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
  Logger.log('Active Ranges: ' + ranges[i].getA1Notation());
}

If I put this into a script triggered on Edit, then it results in the two ranges A1:B4 and D1:E4 displayed in the exec log AND in the spreadsheet those ranges are highlighted after execution.
However, if I comment out
var rangeList = activeSheet.getRangeList(['A1:B4', 'D1:E4']);
rangeList.activate();

and then I specifically select those ranges with the mouse before pasting something into them all at the same time, the script still only recognises the first range.
Is there something similar to the line "activate" that I need to do in order to light up the user-selected ranges?
Many thanks in advance
